# getContent() not showing config link in Prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm currently writing a Prestashop module, and I'm trying to create a configuration page.

Following the docs and reading another modules, I've ended trying this snippet to test:

```
<?php
public function getContent() {
    return '<h1>Config</h1>';
}
```

If I install the module, Prestashop redirects me to a page like this

[image: Config page working]

Which is correct. But in the admin Prestashop does not generate the configuration link.

[image: configuration link not showing]

The question is: what the heck I need to do to show that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `config.xml` file of your module there's a `is_configurable` option :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<module>
    <name>blocktopmenu</name>
    <displayName><![CDATA[Top horizontal menu]]></displayName>
    <version><![CDATA[2.2.3]]></version>
    <description><![CDATA[Adds a new horizontal menu to the top of your e-commerce website.]]></description>
    <author><![CDATA[PrestaShop]]></author>
    <tab><![CDATA[front_office_features]]></tab>
    <is_configurable>1</is_configurable>
    <need_instance>1</need_instance>
    <limited_countries></limited_countries>
</module>
```

It is also configurable from the module constructor:

```
<?php 
class MyModule extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
        // ...
        $this->is_configurable = true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! Looking at the XML I felt like they were the same object members of the constructor and tried the `$this->is_configurable = true` line. Edited to share my approach based on your answer. Thank you :)